# how to get date from table then store it to variable in php

Tags: php

I have a table that stores current_date by timestamp when users get registered.

```
seeker
name.. current_date
ali...2012-04-22 22:12:36
```

Now I have to store this date in some variable.  I am using this query:

```
$uname= $_REQUEST['name2']; 

$qry5= "select current_date from seeker where name='$uname'";
                $res4=mysql_query($qry5, $con);
                $rs5= mysql_result($res4,0); 
                echo $rs5;
```

This query should return the date that is stored in the correspondence of user "2012-04-22", but this query returns the date of today "2012-05-02".  Please tell me where I made mistakes. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shuld think about security a little bit. Your code is prone to SQL-Injection attacks.

Comment: FYI, this query includes a serious security flaw - not only could I send a username for some other user and get data that is not mine, you're vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.  See [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

[`CURRENT_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-date) is a special keyword in MySQL which returns today's date, as a synonym to the function `CURDATE()`.  It should work if you enclose the column in backquotes, but it may be better to rename the column to something not in conflict with a MySQL keyword.  Since the value the column actually holds is not *the current date*, but rather a user's registration date, I would suggest renaming it to something like `registration_date`.

```
// Enclose current_date in backquotes as `current_date`
$qry5= "select `current_date` from seeker where name='$uname'";
```

Also, don't forget to escape `$uname`, as it is currently vulnerable to SQL inejction.

```
$uname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name2']);
```